# Compiling QT 6.4.2 without SSL

Tags: qt, qt6

I have a system running redhat 7.9 which I am not allowed to do system changes to. The system does not have openssl installed.

I am trying to configure QT with:

```
./configure -release -no-ssl -no-openssl
```

This gives me this error message which I cant seem to resolve:

```
+ mkdir -p qtbase
+ cd qtbase
+ exec /home/osfas/osmiv/projects/qt/qt-everywhere-src-6.4.2/qtbase/configure -top-level -release -no-ssl -no-openssl
cmake: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I am trying to understand how the configuration work but I am struggling.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to figure out that the error. `ldd cmake` revailed a dependency til libssl1.so.1.1

So the error has nothing to do with QT configure